# Setting the Scale of an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm creating a website which hosts games, and like many, I use the wonderful `<iframe>` tag to get the game from a seperate directory. I am trying to get the `<iframe>` to size itself to 600px wide and let the height automatically adjust itself.

I have tried using the CSS `transform` property, but it has to be a percent, not an amount in pixels. I have also tried using Javascript to get the scroll height and the scroll width of the `<iframe>` and set the width to 600px while setting the height to the height of the content.

Here's my markup, script, and stylesheet.

HTML:

```
<div class="game-border" id="gameBack">
<iframe src="http://superfungames.com/tetris/" class="game-frame" id="gameCont" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
<!-- Counteract the evil effects of centering the game-border and game-frame by using position absolute !-->
<div class="breaker" id="breaker"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var gameBack = document.getElementById('gameBack');
var breaker = document.getElementById('breaker');
var iFrame = document.getElementById('gameCont');

var iframeWin = iFrame.contentWindow || iFrame.contentDocument.parentWindow;
var iFrameHeight = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;

iFrame.style.height = iFrameHeight + 'px';

gameBack.style.height = gameBack.scrollHeight + 25 + 'px';
gameBack.style.width = gameBack.scrollWidth + 25 + 'px';

//Counteract position absolute. Additional number is like margin-top.
breaker.style.height = gameBack.scrollHeight + 10 + 'px';
```

CSS:

```
.game-frame {
width: 600px;
height: auto;
overflow: visible;
}

.game-border {
background-color: #63d68f;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
overflow: visible;
}
```

I expect that the `<iframe>` would be 600px wide and the height of the content tall, however, it is 600px and only has the very top of the content showing.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: @Dat Boi Trump No

Answer (score 0):

The iframe tag counts with a width attribute, you only need to add `width="{number_of_pixels}"`. Example: `<iframe src="{any_website_url}" widht="600"></iframe>`, this sets the width to 600px.

It should work in most sites (I guess), however this doesn't work with the website you are using. It seems that it uses some script that redirects you to their websit instead of displaying it in an iframe.

To solve this you can add the attribute `sandbox`. This will block some features of the website, like the one that redirects you to their website. Example: `<iframe src="{any_website_url}" sandbox></iframe>`. I am not sure if this will break anything about the game itself. You can try to investigate more.

**Your HTML will be something like this. There is no need to change the js file nor the css file.**

```html
<div class="game-border" id="gameBack">
    <iframe src="http://superfungames.com/tetris/" width='600' class="game-frame" id="gameCont" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox></iframe>
</div>
    <!-- Counteract the evil effects of centering the game-border and game-frame by using position absolute !-->
<div class="breaker" id="breaker"></div>
```

#### More info:

- [HTML iframe width attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_width.asp)
- [Why does `<iframe src=“https://”></iframe>` redirect the page in IE 11?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40187099)